# SVN fails Clean-Up due to work queue (Unreal Engine 4)

Tags: svn, unreal-engine4

We shared a UE4 Project and I was committing stuff when an error occured. Now it's impossibile to do a SVN clean-up.
I searched all over this site and on the web but nothing seems to resolve our problem.
The error says:

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
F:\****
Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with
'F:\****', work item 8623 (file-install **** 1 0 1 1)
Impossible to find the specified path.
```

the **** is the incriminated path.
Closing all instances of UE4 or create a fake asset or using SQLite doesn't work at all, or maybe i'm missing something?

Thanks in advance! I'm not a programmer, so please, if you want to answer, keep it simple as much as possible!

Comment: It your working copy is corrupted it's far easier to just create a new one. You shouldn't be fiddling with SQLite unless you're a Subversion developer.